# Order of columns in index - insert performance

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I've done a bit of research on the order of index columns but am not 100% sure so please bear with me on this!
I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Valuation]
    (  
      [ValuationID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                          NOT NULL
                          CONSTRAINT [PK_Valuation] PRIMARY KEY ,  
      VersionID INT NOT NULL ,  
      AlphanumericIdentifier VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  
      ...  
      other columns  
      ...  
    )
```

I do many joins on this table to others on VersionID and AlphanumericIdentifier, so I put an index on it:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Valuation] ON [dbo].[Valuation]   
(
[VersionID] ASC,
[AlphanumericIdentifier] ASC
)
```

Two questions:

1. These joins are usually done for a specific VersionID, so this is the most selective column and should be the first in the index - correct?
2. Inserts are always done for a single version, which is 1 more than the last version. This should mitigate the performance hit on inserts as the inserted rows are a 'chunk' that can be added to the end of the index. Is this right?

I'm pretty sure that I'm right on 1, but is 2 correct?

Thanks
Joe

Comment: Are you using the identity column for anything? Is the combination of VersionID + Alphenumericidentifier unique? Maybe you should consider the PK on the two columns instead of on the identity column if it isn't in fact going to be used.

Comment: It sounds like `VersionID` should be the PK (and an Identity)

Comment: VersionID + Alphenumericidentifier are not unique. They **should** be unique in conjunction with another varchar field but I can't introduce a unique index at this stage of the project due to the risk involved. But sounds like a good idea if I could turn back time...  Another constraint is I need to send a unique id to a 3rd party vendor in a file. This would be up to 10+255+255=560 chars which will probably cause problems on their side. At the moment we just send them an int PK, which at only up to 10 chars is ok

Comment: Don't ever accept poor design in the interest of time. You will just spend more and more time accounting for it in the future instead of correcting the ship as soon as you find the problem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - agreed. The source system is a database but with no constraints. We could and should enforce constraints when importing the data, e.g. using max() or sum() to deal with dupes. I thought a while back that unique indexes had a greater perf hit on insert than non-unique but further reading suggests that the hit is negligible

Answer (score 1):

To your questions:

"These joins are usually done for a specific VersionID, so this is the most selective column and should be the first in the index."

Joins have nothing to do with it, unless the joins are being used as a filter.
 Filters (Where clause predicates) and Sorting (Order By clauses) use indices.  Whether an index will be used depends on how many records (rows) satisfy the filter.  If the query will return every row in the table, (no where clause) then in all likelihood, no index will be used, because the query optimizer will decide(correctly) that it might as well just read the entire table than try to use an index.  Indices are hierarchical tree structures, with multiple levels.   Using an index requires one Disk I/O per index level for each row that will be returned by the query.  So if the query will return all 1000 rows in a table, and there are five levels in the index, then this would require 5000 IOs.  Reading the data directly from the table, instead of the index, would only require 1000 IOs.

Next, your statement about "This should mitigate the performance hit on inserts as the inserted rows are a 'chunk' that can be added to the end of the index"

This statement is only true if the index is a clustered index.  In your schema, the clustered index is the Primary Key (because although you can override it, that's the default behavior) which is on `ValuationID`, not on `VersionId`.  So inserts of "chunks" of ***any*** records, whether they all have the same versionId, or not, will be added at the end of the index because they will all have new `valuationId`s.

Comment: OK thanks - makes sense re the joins. I do a join and then have versionID in the where clause so the optimiser will figure out to use the index on Valuation as it's ordered by versionid and then also use a similar index on the table it's joined to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right on both.

The columns should be ordered according to the ones you query more, with the leading column the one you always, or most often, query.

Adding rows with incrementing values of `VersionID` means that intermediate pages don't need to be split.